# virsh / qemu external snapshots fail with more than one disk

Tags: backup, qemu, snapshot, virsh

I am running into this problem and have found no answer in my research. There is a similar post on SuperUser that hasn't had a comment, much less an answer, in close to 10 months. Maybe that is not the best place for it since it's related to KVM/virsh/QEMU on Linux.

Works fine:

```
sudo virsh snapshot-create-as --domain TEST_RUNNINGDISKS --name "backup-TEST_RUNNINGDISKS" --no-metadata --atomic --disk-only --diskspec vda,snapshot=external
```

Does not work:

```
sudo virsh snapshot-create-as --domain TEST_RUNNINGDISKS --name "backup-TEST_RUNNINGDISKS" --no-metadata --atomic --disk-only --diskspec vda,snapshot=external --diskspec vdb,snapshot=external
```

Returns:

```
error: internal error: unable to execute QEMU command 'transaction': Could not create file: Permission denied
```

I also tried this directly through use of QEMU QMP.

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
TEST='{"execute":"transaction","arguments":{"actions":[{"type":"blockdev-snapshot-sync","data":{"device":"drive-virtio-disk0","snapshot-file":"/media/data/kvm/TEST_RUNNINGDISKS-backup.qcow2"}},{"type":"blockdev-snapshot-sync","data":{"device":"drive-virtio-disk1","snapshot-file":"/media/data/kvm/TEST_RUNNINGDISKS-1-backup.qcow2"}}]}}'
virsh qemu-monitor-command TEST_RUNNINGDISKS --pretty $TEST
```

Error:

```
sudo ./test.sh
{  "id": "libvirt-83",  "error": {    "class": "GenericError",
    "desc": "Could not create file: Permission denied"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The version of qemu-kvm that was included in the Ubuntu packages for 18.04 is 2.11 which is *really* old and apparently did not have the ability to handle multiple disks in this manner. I did a wipe and reload to 20.04 which includes qemu-kvm version 4.2. The symptom is no more.

- Non-working: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/qemu-kvm
- Working: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/qemu-kvm